# InDesign export to interactive PDF makes some, but not all, images pixelated

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, image-quality

This is a similar question to one asked before, although not recently. I'm exporting a long, narrow ID document (5.5" x 32") to Interactive PDF. There's one image at the top of the document and one at the bottom. Once exported, the top image looks great, but the bottom image is pixelated — and this has happened on two different documents.

My compression settings are: Compression: JPEG 2000 (Lossless)  /  JPEG Quality: Maximum  /  Resolution (ppi): 144

Both images are of the same resolution etc (both from the same camera and photo shoot).

Any thoughts on what might be making the bottom image pixelated?

Comment: What is the *Effective PPI* of the pixelated image? Are you sure it hasn't been scaled? Are you sure the pixelated image isn't missing or needs to be updated? Check the *Links* panel.

Comment: The Effective PPI is 400, which is more than enough and it doesn't need to be updated and it isn't missing. Looks perfect in the ID doc, just pixelated in interactive PDF.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the images. Sometimes people mean different things when they say "pixelated". You could make a PDF with the images side by side and make a screenshot. It can just be a small crop of each if you don't want to reveal the full images.

Comment: I'm not able to share even a crop of the images publicly. But rest assured I know what pixelated images look like. It's not my analysis of the issue that's the problem, it's what is happening to one of the images.

Comment: Yeah OK, it's just a common misunderstanding here. Can be hard to explain visual issues in words. Do you mean pixelated like in low resolution (larger pixels) than the other image or do you mean poor interpolation (jagged edges)? Does the two images have different resolution in the PDF? Does the same thing happen if you copy the two images to another document and position them differently?